# matlab has encountered an internal prob and needs to close when installing Add-Ons

Tags: matlab, arduino, internal, add-on

i'm working with Matlab 2015 and I'd like to install the hardware add-ons to work with Arduino. But when I click on Add-Ons -> Get Hardware Support Packages I get the following error: [*matlab has encountered an internal problem and needs to close*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHGM1.png)

Comment: Probably a bug in MATLAB, contact the support.